# jQAssistant Scanner for Method Parameter

Tags: jqassistant

I am currently struggeling with the development of an custom jQAssistant Scanner.

##### Background:

```
public class MyEntityDAOImpl {

public MyEntity getMyEntity(){
final TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = getEntityManager()
                .createNamedQuery(MyEntity.QUERY_NAME, MyEntity.class);
return getResult(query);
}

}
```

A Method getMyEntity() is using JPA Named Queries to get a matching result from the database.
The query name is as static final String constant of the MyEntity class.

##### Task:

In order to perfrom quality quecks in our project, I would need to know which named query is called by the getMyEntity() method. I would like to develop a custom scanner to extend my Neo4J DB to look something like this:

[image]

I would use RegEx matching to get the String literal "MyEntity.QUERY_NAME". Ideally I would even like to get the String value of this variable, but the literal should suffice.
My Question is, know how to attach the new node to the existing (:Java:PublicMethod) one.
Do I need to extend the JavaScanner?

I am just starting to work with jQAssistant and any help is greatly appreciated!

Best, Patrick